# How to solve line discontinuity in html table (python fpdf2 generate PDF documents)

Tags: html, pdf, html-table, line-breaks, pyfpdf

I try to generate a PDF document. I use [PYPDF2](https://pypi.org/project/PyPDF2/). The PDF contains a table which is generated by :

```
class HTMLMixin:
    HTML2FPDF_CLASS = HTML2FPDF

    def write_html(self, text, *args, **kwargs):
        """Parse HTML and convert it to PDF"""
        kwargs2 = vars(self)
        # Method arguments must override class & instance attributes:
        kwargs2.update(kwargs)
        h2p = self.HTML2FPDF_CLASS(self, *args, **kwargs2)
        text = html.unescape(text)  # To deal with HTML entities
        h2p.feed(text)
```

I did not write this class, it is part of the library. Certain columns however has more content so they contains line-breaks. Because of these line-breaks the result is like this: [image]

How can I have full, continuous side-lines for each columns in the table? (Just like for column 'Teilnehmer')

Answer (score 1):

This is a current limitation of the library, reported here on the project bug tracker: https://github.com/PyFPDF/fpdf2/issues/91

The documentation also lists the limitations of the `HTMLMIxin`: https://pyfpdf.github.io/fpdf2/HTML.html#supported-html-features

> Notes:
>
> - tables should have at least a first `<th>` row with a `width` attribute.
> - currently multi-line text in table cells is not supported. Contributions are welcome to add support for this feature!